# Symfony2: Input on infinite-running command

Tags: symfony, command

I'm creating a simple 'server console' application in symfony2, that'll never actually stop running, but I wan't the user to be also able to enter commands into the running console command.
But on my command there is no input prompt.

Thank you for help, hice3000.

Comment: What have you tried? Every running console command has an input cursor. In your console command you have to read from the InputStream.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so i post this in an answer

This question is more about PHP the symfony2 in specific. How do you make something run continiously while something else checks for input commands? Well threading would be good for this, but since PHP support is not really great for threading you can spawn another proces instead.